# How to restore backup correctly?

Tags: backup, fedora

I forgot to setup options using 'cp', so all permissions and ownership of made backup are default.
I copied the next directories:

- /etc
- /bin
- /home
- /lib
- /opt
- /sbin
- /usr
- /var

I am using Fedora 13.
So, how can I restore correctly previous directories to my current reinstalled system, what permissions and ownership should this directories and files to be? My default account is 'master'.
Also I want to see copied program icons in Gnome menu but they are empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rpm -a --setperms --setugids` will handle the system directories. You're on your own for `/home` and `/srv`.

Also, `rsync -a`.

Comment: Thanks, and also there will be f.e. /etc/passwd permitted successfully? I mean is this will set perms and etc to ALL files in system directories? And how can I update programs icons?

Comment: It will reset all permissions and ownership on all entries in the rpmdb. The icons should come back once all your permissions are correct.

Comment: Ok it works, also I fixed some problems with perms of auditd config files and some another services. But now I have another problem - after starting login window dont show available users and I can't change keyboard layout, what maybe the problem?